# random function in C++ and Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, random

I have a code written in Matlab , and I  wrote it in C++, but I don't this don't give the same results.

The problem is that I use random function in 3 parts of the code, when I make the random functions fixed , both codes gave the same output.

If any body have any ideas please help me.

Comment: Obviously the two random number functions give different sequences.

Comment: but if I run the program multiple time on matlab  it gives results near each other. so is there a away to make the 2 random function gives near results?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of the `rand` functions will differ.

You can control the Matlab version through [`rng`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/rng.html).

On the C++ end, I suggest using the functionality in (C++11) [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) (or use [Boost's version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) if your environment is lacking decent C++11 library support) . I can't test right now, but it seems like both sides support the Mersenne Twister. With a bit of luck, the implementation will generate the same numbers if you choose the same seed.

I can't test this now as I don't have Matlab here.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `rand()` function give you same numbers. It is better to use `srand (time(NULL));` before you call `rand()` function. `srand (time(NULL));` makes `rand()` to produce different outputs.

For using `srand (time(NULL));` function, you should add `#include <time.h>` or `#include <ctime>` in your code.

Comment: I used a srand(time(NULL)) only once in the code, before the first rand() function i used in the code. how can i make the result in matlab and c++ be the same????

Comment: I don't got your meaning. However I thought your problem is in C++.

Comment: I mean i used the srand(time(Null)) in order to make the rand() produce different outputs. I want to keep matlab and c++ random , but i want to get similar results after running code from them.

Comment: I think it is not possible. For this purpose, you should give same inputs in C++ and Matlab. `rand()` function produces different outputs.

Comment: but it's not my first code, i tried before different codes in matlab and c++ which contains random function , and it gives similar results. but in this code i have certain loop when i entered it once i got same result from matlab and c++ but if i entered it n times the results became different. thanks for your efforts